# Random number generation in AnyLogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

The code releases the first element of "wait", and randomly assigns the element to a service (simulator or gym), if there is space available in the service, based on certain conditions.

If a random number has been generated but it does not lead to a valid service, the code generates a new random number up to 100 times before breaking out of the loop.

```
if (wait.size() > 1 && (simulators.size() < 6 || Gym.size() < 15)) {
// Free the current wait and pick a service at random
wait.free(wait.get(0));
Random rand = new Random();
int iterations = 0;

while (true) {
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt(2) + 1; 
    if (randomNum == 1 && simulators.size() < 6) {
        // Choose the simulator service if there's space available
        wait.get(0).var_simulatorService = true;
        break;
    } else if (randomNum == 2 && Gym.size() < 15 && wait.get(0).par_allowForGym == true) {
        // Choose the gym service if there's space available
        wait.get(0).var_Gym = true;
        traceln("The agent number " + wait.get(0)+ " Alllow to go Gym - " + wait.get(0).par_allowForGym);
        break;
    } else {
        // generate a new random number if the previous one didn't lead to a valid service
        iterations++;
        if (iterations >= 100) {
            traceln("The agent number " + wait.get(0)+ " Alllow to go Gym - " + wait.get(0).par_allowForGym);
            break;
        }
    }
}}
```

[image]

On the basis of this code when `wait.get(0).par_allowForGym == false` then the loop will run(100 times) unless the random value become 1, but based on this error that never happen and loop break.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should never code `while (true)`. Although you specify break conditions, it is bad practice because you can not debug this (as you now experience right here :) ).

Best avoid `while` loops altogether, there are only very rare cases where you need them.

Rewrite your code using a for-loop or some entirely different setup. In your case, you may want to try a `switch` syntax or simple if-else logic for the `rand` value.

Comment: i did try switch but i want to generate the random number once no condition gets true, and that is only possible using while or do while. What i did is i only run the while for 10 times, if still no condition gets true using the random generated numbers, then  the loop will be closed. now when " wait.get(0).par_allowForGym == false " then no condition matches for it does not matter how many times new random number gets generated. Kindly take a look at question i update it with new code.

Comment: Try simplifying the example, too much code to sift through. Boil it down so it can be understood within 30 sec or so :) All these conditions are too confusing... (by doing that, you likely find the issue yourself anyway :) )

Comment: (And you can *ALWAYS* code without while loops, you just need to think about it differently. This is similar to state charts: Never use "condition-based" transitions as you can always replace them with other constructs)

Comment: Feel free to repost and ask how to code what you need (showing what you did already and what you actually want to achieve)

Comment: I again edit the question with simple code kindly take a look.